# Nuxt - asyncData ERROR: "Binding element '$axios' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js, typeerror

Following the docs here: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/setup

I get this error logged to console when running `yarn dev`:

```
ERROR  ERROR in pages/index.vue:51:21                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           23:01:53
TS7031: Binding element '$axios' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    49 |   }
    50 | 
  > 51 |   async asyncData({ $axios }) {
       |                     ^^^^^^
    52 |     const ip = await $axios.get('http://icanhazip.com')
    53 |     return { ip }
    54 |   }
```

I have triple checked that I have `'@nuxtjs/axios'` in my `nuxt.config.js` and `tsconfig.json`.

What am I missing? It worked for the first while then this error showed up and I have no idea why?!

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you have `@nuxt/types` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes, I do have it in there. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asyncData` is passed an argument called context, which has a corresponding type in `@nuxt/types` called `Context`. Import `Context` from `@nuxt/types` then declare the type of the destructured argument like this:

```
async asyncData({ $axios } : Context) {
  const ip = await $axios.get('http://icanhazip.com')
  return { ip }
}
```